# php select option storing wrong option

Tags: php

I have a selection drop-down list and I have the value I want to be selected so I have a comparison to get that value and make it the selected option. The problem is that when I look at the code in the debugger the code seems to go through the **If** side and then the **Else** side of the comparison for each of the items in the table of options. I'm sure it is something stupid in my code, but I can't spot it. Maybe it will be apparent to someone. Here is the code

```
                    <select name="cust_code" id="cust_code">
                     <?php foreach ( $customers as $option ) : ?>
                        <? if ($option->refno == $cust_code){
                            ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $option->refno; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $option->company; ?></option>

                            <?
                        }
                        else {
                            ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $option->refno; ?>"><?php echo $option->company; ?></option>
                            <?
                        }
                        ?>



                     <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
```

Comment: I just changed it to = from == to see if that was the problem. It still didn't work

Comment: It doesn't work with ==

Comment: the problem still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `==` for comparison (or `===` for exact comparison).  Using `=` *assigns* the value, and will evaluate to true.

Make your life simpler.

Instead of an entirely new output, simply set the `selected` parameter based on your if condition:

```
<?php foreach ( $customers as $option ) :
    // Create the selected parameter if the values match
    $selected = ($option->refno == $cust_code) ? ' selected' : '';
?>
     <option value="<?php echo $option->refno; ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $option->company; ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Finally, if the problem exists after changing to `==`, then you should output the contents of your comparison variables within your loop:

```
echo '<br>' . $option->refno . ' == ' . $cust_code;
```

This will allow you to see what's happening and debug the issue.

Comment: I am trying your bit of code but it seems to need a bit of tweaking as I get an error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>>' (T_SR) in "

Comment: @Geoff - whoops.  Missing ? mark in closing php tag (fixed above): `<?php echo $selected; ?>`

Comment: I put that in but then get an empty drop down list.

Comment: @Geoff - no, that's not the issue.  What do you see when you view source?  I suspect you're missing one of the `>` brackets.  Notice that there's one right after the closing `?>` tag here: `<?php echo $selected; ?> > <?php`

Comment: This is my whole line:`<option value="<?php echo $option->refno; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?> <?php echo $option->company; ?></option>`

Comment: @Geoff - yeah, that's wrong.  See what the answer contains - your missing a `>` in there.  Should be `<option value="<?php echo $option->refno; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $option->company; ?></option>`

Comment: Apologies, you are right, was blind. I should have had that extra > and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For comparisons, you should use `==` (comparison) instead of `=` (assignment)

Comment: yes that was a wrong experiment as I mentioned above. I have corrected it and it is still a problem

Comment: In your debugger, make sure the $option->refno and $cust_code values are populated and the expected value.

Comment: thanks I did that and all seems ok. i am changing the code in line with cale_b below.